# mod_rewrite - strange [R] behavior

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes

I'm doing something very simple with mod_rewrite and it's behaving strange. It's behaving as if I'm using the [R] option, but I'm not. Here's a simple test for a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^page1$ page2
```

This should redirect a request for page1 to page2, but leave the URL in the web browser still pointing to page1. That doesn't happen though. It actually switches the URL to page2, as if I were using this code:

```
RewriteRule ^page1$ page2 [R]
```

Why's it doing that? That's not the default behavior. I'm using a pre-configured machine I got for EC2, so it's probably something in the apache configuration I'm not aware of. Googling has been futile. Help?

This is Apache 2.12 btw.

Comment: What does the rewrite log tells you?

Comment: When I enable RewriteLog according to the specs (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog), I get a 500 Error. Grrrr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it... not exactly sure what I did (doh!) because I futzed around with it a bunch.
I'll try to to some investigative work so I can share the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[DirectorySlash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) is often the culprit. If not, and no further rewriting is done, consider using [L]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, that's not it... any other ideas?